# Conditional parameter without using if-else?

Tags: python, design-patterns, strategy-pattern

I have a program that is working fine at the moment.

```
from abc import ABC, abstractmethod


class User():
    def __init__(self, transport_strategy):
        self.transport_strategy = transport_strategy
    def transport(self):
        self.transport_strategy.transport()

class TransportStrategy():
    @abstractmethod
    def transport(self):
        pass

class WalkStrategy(TransportStrategy):
    def transport(self):
        print("I walk")

class FlyStrategy(TransportStrategy):
    def transport(self):
        print("I fly")

if __name__ == "__main__":
    u1 = User(FlyStrategy())
    u1.transport()
    u2 = User(WalkStrategy())
    u2.transport()
```

Now I need to make it accept parameters in cli mode.
e.g. `python example.py --strategy=fly`

I can code like this but it violates the purpose that I used strategy pattern at the start. I want to reduce the unnecessary `if-else` as much as possible.

```
if args.strategy == "fly":
    strategy = FlyStrategy()
elif args.strategy == "walk":
    strategy = WalkStrategy()
```

Comment: Use a dictionary? Also functions are first class citizens in Python, so I don't know if the strategy pattern applies

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understood the question, you can use a dict

```
strategies = {
  "fly": FlyStrategy
  "walk": WalkStrategy
}

if args.strategy not in strategies:
  raise ValueError(f'Unknown strategy: {args.strategy}')
strategy = strategies[args.strategy]()
```